# What's the rationale behind curried functions in Scala?

Tags: scala, currying

I am just new to Scala and it seems a little bit confusing to me why Scala provides "curried functions" such as:

```
//curried function
def add(lhs: Int)(rhs: Int) = lhs + rhs
//so we can do partially binding like
val add1 = add(1)_
```

Its confusing because Scala already provides 'partial application' to normal functions, e.g.,

```
//normal function
def add(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) = lhs + rhs
//also supports partially application
val add1 = add(1, _: Int)
```

So my question is: is there any other point of using a curried function rather than a normal function in Scala besides partial application?

EDT1: Thanks for the replies. I think I have learned new stuff from all the answers below.

Comment: This question and all of the answers are actually referring to Scala's support for _multiple parameter lists_ rather than the concept of _function currying_. As @TomaszNurkiewicz pointed out, only using some of the parameters actually results in a _partially-applied function_ regardless of whether the function has a single parameter list or multiple parameter lists. In practice I guess the difference is kind of trivial, but I still think it's good to keep the terms straight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Putting the theoretical motivations aside (see: [*Contrast with partial function application*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application) in Wikipedia on *currying*), there is a practical implication. The syntax is much simpler and more readable when the last argument is a block of code.

Compare the following methods:

```
def test1(name: String, callback: => Unit) {}
def test2(name: String)(callback: => Unit) {}
```

The second method invocation looks much nicer, compare:

```
test("abc", {
    //some code
})

test2("abc") {
    //some code
}
```

Comment: I'm so glad someone pointed out _partial function application_ here. The conflation of Scala's _multiple parameter lists_ with the concept of _curried functions_ bugs me!

Answer (score 5):

- Nicer syntax: add(1) instead of add(1,_)
- Type inference from the left to the right parameter list. This is used in the fold methods of collections, for example.
- They are also needed for implicit parameter lists.

Of course you could argue that the last two could have been implemented differently.

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with the theory behind currying (as yet), but I know of at least one concrete situation where currying works better: calling a function with a pair of curly braces instead of brackets is only possible for single-parameter functions. So you can do it for a curried function having two parameter lists with a single parameter each, but not for a normal function which has been partially applied for one parameter.

This is especially useful when implementing a control structure or DSL where some parameters of a function are anonymous functions themselves. An example to this is from *Programming in Scala*, section 9.4:

```
val file = new File("date.txt")

withPrintWriter(file) {
  writer => writer.println(new java.util.Date)
}
```