# Scala : Difference between two ways declare a function

Tags: scala, functional-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the rationale behind curried functions in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12635695/whats-the-rationale-behind-curried-functions-in-scala)

I have two difference ways to declare a function: 1) use currying. 2)use function as parameter.

Here is my code :

```
def transform(f: Double => Double)(input: Double) = {
  f(input)
}                                                 

def transformVer2(f: Double => Double, input: Double) = {
  f(input)
}                                                 

transform(x=>x*x)(10)                             //> res8: Double = 100.0
transformVer2(x=>x*x, 10)                         //> res9: Double = 100.0
```

I don't know what the real difference of two above declare of a function. Please tell me.

Thanks :)

Comment: No. I don't think it same to much. In my question, parameter is a function :)

Comment: It doesn't make any difference, it's still the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The former employs currying, the latter is something you're probably more familiar with from languages like C, C++, etc.

Currying is something that is prominent in functional programming languages.. functional programming languages place the idea of functions and function chaining in high regard so something like

```
def transform(f: Double => Double)(input: Double)
```

Can be seen as something that takes as a single argument a function `Double => Double` and returns another function that takes as a single argument a `Double` and returns a `Double`.

As Programming in Scala discusses, function currying also let's us do some nifty things, two of which come to mind are

1. type inference
2. new control abstractions

For type inference, consider something like `foldLeft`.

```
val myVector = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4)
myVector.foldLeft(0.0)(_ + _)
```

`foldLeft` is curried, and us specifying `0.0` as the initial value let's the type inferencer know we want our final result to be a `Double`.

For new control abstractions, we can do something like

```
def doWithFileAndClose(file: File)(func: () => Unit): Unit =
  try { func() } finally { file.close }
```

which would be used like

```
doWithFileAndClose("somefile.txt") {
  /* do stuff */
}
```

This takes advantage that Scala will accept curly braces in place of parentheses, which makes the above look just like familiar control structures such as `for` and `while` loops.

Comment: From declaration of the function transform we do not know that it returns Double.